# IIS7/.NET4 App - How To Prevent Deadlocks?

Tags: iis-7, .net

I have a problem .NET 4 app I'm trying to load on my IIS7 server.  It has a bug where if it gets hit multiple times while it's trying to come up - either initially or from a recycle - it gets deadlocked permanently.

I'm trying to figure out a way to either prevent traffic from coming to it while it's initializing, or in the worst case make the whole thing "single-threaded" so that it can never get two requests in at the same time.  I'm already running just one worker process but that's not doing the trick.  Ideas?  Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a badly written app. I'm not aware of anything you can really do aside from getting the application source looked at and fixed.

Do you have access to the source or the developer?

Comment: Sigh, arguably.  It's one of those eleventh hour things where a code fix would take too long so they're looking for the sysadmin to save the day.

Comment: Yep, in the end we're having to push off the release and make the dev fix it the right way.  I was just hoping there was some at least temporary magic I could pull out...

Comment: I'm sorry about that; I know how it is! +1 for the question though, for the effort!

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding limits to

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Aspnet.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> <configuration>   <system.web>
    <applicationPool 
        maxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU="1"
        maxConcurrentThreadsPerCPU="0" 
        requestQueueLimit="5000" />   </system.web>
    <runtime>
        <legacyUnhandledExceptionPolicy enabled="false" />
        <legacyImpersonationPolicy enabled="true"/>
        <alwaysFlowImpersonationPolicy enabled="false"/>
        <SymbolReadingPolicy enabled="1" />
        <shadowCopyVerifyByTimestamp enabled="true"/>
    </runtime>
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true" /> </configuration>
```

per [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/tmarq/asp-net-thread-usage-on-iis-7-5-iis-7-0-and-iis-6-0).

But it didn't work, it still deadlocked.  Tried setting the threads to 1 as well, but then the worker process won't even start.